# Attach events to grid DOM

Tags: javascript, extjs

I want to drag from an ExtJS grid row into a textarea field at a certain position in the textarea.

HTML5's Drag API supports such drag/drop operations (http://jsfiddle.net/a98bwb07/3/), but I did not find that ExtJS supports this, so I wanted to use the HTML5 Drag API:

```
document.getElementById('img').addEventListener('dragstart', function (e) {
    e.dataTransfer.setData("text", '[img]' + this.id + '[/img]');
    e.dataTransfer.setDragImage(this, 0,0);
});
```

I tried to add a delegated event on the grid:

```
grid.on({
    dragstart: {
        fn: function(e) {
            console.log(e);
        },
        delegate: grid.getView().rowSelector
    }
})
```

but it isn't fired. (https://fiddle.sencha.com/#view/editor&fiddle/2dac)

How can I attach the dragstart event to all grid rows in a fashion that survives grid refresh and data changes?

Comment: Can you provide up to what you done?

Comment: @swarooppallapothu Done.

Comment: What is your requirement. I mean after drag you want to copy row to textarea?

Comment: @swarooppallapothu I want to insert some text, created from the row content, into the textarea content, at the cursor position. Check out the jsfiddle, try to drag the image into the textarea and you will see that you can insert text at any position in the textarea. I want to do the same, in ExtJS, from an ExtJS grid row.

Comment: You need to attach it to an element of the grid, not the grid itself.

Comment: @EvanTrimboli I have just tried that, but there I only get some mouse event, not a Drag API event. The mouse event does not have the `dataTransfer` property that has to be filled.

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to add element : 'body' to dragstart [fiddle](https://fiddle.sencha.com/#view/editor&fiddle/2db0)

Comment: Thank you, now I get an event at last. But I am stuck again, because that event is a mouse event, not a Drag API event, so the `dataTransfer` property is not available.